# X, Y are iid from N(0,1). What's the probability that X>2Y

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I was thinking, since $X, Y$ are from $N(0,1)$ and they are independent, then

$X - 2Y$ has a distribution of $N(0, 5)$. Then $X-2Y > 0$ has probability of $1/2$.

The above seems correct to me, though it seems like then $X>nY$  would have probability of $1/2$. That seems a bit wrong. Did I get anything wrong?

Comment: What seems 'a bit wrong' there? Are you thinking about the conditional probability perhaps? ($P(X>nY|Y)$ ... that's not the probability in question)

Comment: If I understood you right the results $\frac{1}{2}$ seems not intuitive for you. But even in case if n is large Y is positive with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ (and negative with probability $\frac{1}{2}$). Although |X| is unlikely to be larger than |nY|, the probability without absolute values is reasonalby $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With a bivariate standard normal (i.e. iid standard normal), the probability of lying on one side of a line through the origin is $\frac{_1}{^2}$ no matter what the slope of the line is.

[image]

This follows, for example, from the rotational symmetry of the bivariate distribution about $O$, since we could rotate the problem to one of considering $P(X'\gt0)$ in rotated coordinates.

Indeed, considering the use of affine transformations means it must be $\frac{_1}{^2}$ much more generally -- the argument will apply to any bivariate normal where both variances are greater than 0.

Comment: Thanks, I just found my conclusion a bit counterintuitive, but your diagram makes all this clear to me.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are zero-mean jointly normal random variables (not necessarily independent), then $X-aY$ is a zero-mean normal random variable and thus $$P\{X > aY\} = P\{X-aY > 0\} = \frac 12.$$ Independence and variances have nothing to do with the matter: all that is needed for the above result to hold is that the variables be _jointly_ normal and that the means be zero.  (Trivial exception when $X-aY$ equals $0$, that is, it is a degenerate normal random variable a.k.a. a constant which happens when $X$ and $Y$ are perfectly correlated and $\sigma_X = a\sigma_Y$).

Comment: Thanks Dilip, your comment is of course completely correct - I was starting with the conditions as given and attempting to give some motivation for the result the OP had already derived.

Comment: @DilipSarwate could u pls explain why the variance is not important here. For instance if X ~N(0,2) and Y ~ N(0,1), is P(X > Y) = 1/2. If so, why is it that the variance doesnt change our answer? Thanks

Comment: @quantrader23 One _definition_ of _joint normality_  of $X$ and $Y$ is that $cX+dY$ is a normal random variable for _all_ choices of $c$ and $d$. So, choose $c=1,d=-1$ to get that $X-Y$ is a normal random variable. If $X$ and $Y$ are zero-mean, so is $X-Y$. So, we get $$\frac 12 = P(X-Y>0) = P(X>Y)$$ without having to consider variances or independence: _joint_ normality of $X$ and $Y$ is all that we need. There is a trivial exception when $X$ and $Y$ are perfectly (positively or negatively) correlated jointly normal random variables, as noted in my previous comment.