# Probability that X > Y when X ~ N(0,2) and Y ~ N(0,1)

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, independence

$X$ and $Y$ are independent variables $X$ ~ $N(0,2)$ and $Y$ ~ $N(0,1)$. What is the probability that $X > Y$? I understand that the distribution of $X - Y$ ~ $N(0,3)$ assuming they are independent. Then it should be plausible that:

$$
P(X > Y) = P(X - Y > 0)
$$

$X - Y$ has a mean of $0$ so I think it is probably equally likely that $X - Y > 0$ or $< 0$. However, I am not sure of this approach, especially if the last part is correct.

Comment: Isn't this already covered by Dilip's comments (and in part by statements in the question) in the thread you commented on before posting this? Specifically I mean the comments under this answer:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144955/x-y-are-iid-from-n0-1-whats-the-probability-that-x2y/144957 ... given you clearly knew of its existence, why not at least link it in your question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fact that the distribution of $X-Y$ has mean $0$ does NOT imply that $\mathbb{P}(X-Y<0)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X-Y>0)$ are equal.

So for the last step it is not enough that $X-Y$ has mean $0$, you need that $X-Y$ is *symmetric* around $0$, which is true because $X-Y$ is normally distributed with mean $0$.

Comment: This is a very good and insightful answer.  Why is the downvote?

Comment: You could say $X-Y$ has a symmetric distribution about $0$ here since $X$ and $Y$ each do and they are independent. This gives $P(X>Y)=P(X<Y)$.  Since they are both continuous distributions, you can then say $P(X=Y)=0$ and so $P(X>Y)=\frac12$.

Answer (score 8):

Your reasoning seems right. You can always do some simulation to check if your answer is correct.

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(10000, 0, 2)
y <- rnorm(10000, 0, 1)

sum(x>y)/length(x)
```

Which gives a value of $0.504$.  Which checks out.

EDIT: Note that, as others have pointed out, the last line,  by itself, is not enough. One example is

```
set.seed(1234)

x <- rnorm(10000)
y <- c(rnorm(9000, 1, 1), rnorm(1000, -9, 1))
mean(x-y) #0.01
sum(x>y)/length(x) #0.32
```

Comment: As @user133281 pointed out, the "reasoning" is actually not right. The correct reasoning is that $X - Y \sim N(0, 3)$.

Comment: Well, he does have that, above, but yeah, the final sentence, by itself, is not correct.

Comment: Note, too, that `rnorm(...,0,2)` does not implement the intended meaning of "$N(0,2)$" in the question.  The former has a variance of $2^2=4$ while the latter has a variance of $2.$

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add another simulation implemented in R.
First, we can define PDFs for either random variable:

```
> pdf_x <- function(x) dnorm(x = x, mean = 0, sd = 2)
> pdf_y <- function(x) dnorm(x = x, mean = 0, sd = 1)
```

Then, we can visualize the result:

[image: PDFs of X and Y]

For the case of $X > Y$, we define the following indicator function for later integration:

```
> ind_x <- Vectorize(function(x)
    if (pdf_x(x = x) > pdf_y(x = x)) 1 else 0)
```

We can now integrate the PDF of $X$, for the case $X > Y$:

```
> stats::integrate(
    f = function(x) ind_x(x = x) * pdf_x(x = x),
    lower = -Inf, upper = Inf)

0.4966401 with absolute error < 8e-05
```